# While building web crawler using scrapy , twisted failed to establish internet connection

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, twisted

I am trying to build a web crawler using scrapy . Code of my crawler is as below:

```
import scrapy


class SpiSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spi'
    start_urls = ['http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.css('title:text').extract()
        yield('at:',titles)
```

when I tried to run it , following errors occured :

```
2020-02-20 16:10:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-02-20 16:10:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed
cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:34 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2020-02-20 16:10:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed
cleanly.>]
```

I have tried changing my USER AGENT and try to apply proxy but no it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You don't have to apologize. If you still want to, write it in comments.

Comment: Mmm, are you sure the url is 'http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/'? Because that doesn't work xD

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem it is pretty simple and the solution is even easier.

http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/ does not exists, the url you want is http://quotes.toscrape.com/

Now you will have other problems like the pseudoclass `:text` does not exists, but that is just changing the code to fit the html